# Error on HTTP Stream PHP

Tags: php, stream, filestream, httpcontext

I have this method:

```
protected function _sendRequest($url, $method, Busca_Cxense_Data $data, $get = null) {
    if (! isset ( $this->_urls [$url] )) {
        throw new Busca_Cxense_Exception_Argument ( "El tipo de url enviado no es valido. (type: {$url})" );
    }
    $url = $this->_urls [$url] . $data->getUrlKey () . ($get ? "$get" : '');
    $httpConfig = array ('http' => array ('method' => $method, 'request_fulluri' => $url, 'ignore_errors' => false ) );
    if ($data->getSendJson ()) {
        $json = $this->_setJson ( $data );
        $header = "Content-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: " . strlen ( $json );
        $httpConfig ['http'] ['content'] = $json;
    } else {
        $header = "Content-Type: text/html";
    }
    $httpConfig ['http'] ['header'] = $header;
    $context = stream_context_create ( $httpConfig );
    $stream = fopen ($url, 'r', false, $context);
    $result = stream_get_contents($stream);
    $headers = stream_get_meta_data($stream);
    fclose($stream);
    if (! $result) {
        print_r ( $data );
        var_dump ( $url );
        print_r ( $httpConfig );
        throw new Busca_Cxense_Exception_MethodCall ( "Bad call. \nString: $json\n" );
    }
    var_dump($result); exit;
    return array ('json' => json_decode ( $result ), 'string' => $result, 'headers' => $headers );
}
```

As you can see, it create a context and open an stream. However, I have a error very strange. If I send this url:

```
http://sandbox.cxsearch.cxense.com/api/search/levelup?p_aq=query%28category^1:%22preview%20trailer%22,token-op=or%29&p_sm=idobject:desc&p_s=0&p_c=20&p_dr=title
```

it throws a bad request error, but if I send this other one:

```
http://sandbox.cxsearch.cxense.com/api/search/levelup?p_q=test&p_sm=idobject:desc&p_s=0&p_c=20&p_dr=title
```

it works as expected. Do I have to encode the url or something?

**FIXED**
I was able to figure what the problem was. I Only need to change the space for %20. And that was all...

Comment: You are sending VERY different key/value pairs in both of those urls. Are you sure you're doing a valid comparison between "working" and "broken"? Apples/Oranges...

Comment: @MarcB Yeap. It is not "very" differente. In the first one I'm sending this data: $data->aq = array ('category' => array ('preview', 'trailer')); and in the second one $data->q = 'test'; Those are diferente kind of searches, so thats why they are different. The system works ok, if you get into the urls they work as expected, but from PHP they don't. The first one throws an 400 error

Comment: I don't know what the system you send the query to allows, but at first glance I would assume the encoded characters in the query may be throwing off the remote server's validator. Perhaps you can't send requests including parenthesis and the such?

Comment: @EmmanuelG I'm converting the characters tu utf8. The most annoying thing is that if you run: curl -XGET "http://sandbox.cxsearch.cxense.com/api/search/levelup?p_aq=query(category:"preview trailer",token-op=or)&p_sm=idobject:desc&p_s=0&p_c=20&p_dr=title" from the console it works as expected... the only problem its in doing via PHP, wether using fopen, get_file_contents or curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure what the problem was. I Only need to change the space for %20. And that was all...

Answer (score 0):

400 response is returned by remote server, so you want to see specs/contact people on that side on how to build correct query.
The urls you provide look very different and remote system might have own validation rules on values, list of provided parameters, etc. Also it might require some specific headers and/or request body.

Comment: The url's aren't the problem. As I have stated before, they work correctly if I open them via browser or console, the first one only miswork if I try to run it via PHP

Comment: >Also it might require some specific headers and/or request body.